# When runing a program with cgexec it fails to find a shared object

Tags: linux, rhel7

I have a proprietary program, let's call it `foo` which depends on a shared object `bar.so` found via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. With this env variable properly set, `ldd` confirms the shared object is found and, more importantly, the program runs fine. However, when I run it with `cgexec -g cpuset:/some_socket foo` it complains that it cannot find `bar.so`. Does anyone know what is going on and how can I fix in order to run `foo` on the specified cpuset?

FWIW: I'm non RHEL 7 and the relevant cpuset does exist.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/27376/why-does-my-ld-library-path-get-unset-launching-terminal

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. That's the answer, thanks.